# spring data jpa @query parsing error

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data

I found very weird bug(?) today. So I just simply want a pagination with searching by two fields for one given input. Desired code:

```
@Query("select c from Customer c where upper(c.name) like %:search% or upper(c.number) like upper(%:search%)")
Page<Customer> findByNameOrNumber(@Param("search") String search, Pageable pageable);
```

But the snippet above throws the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page com.zilliant.webnext.repository.CustomerRepository.findByNameOrNumber(java.lang.String,org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable)!
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:92) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.<init>(SimpleJpaQuery.java:62) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
.......
.......
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.identPrimary(HqlBaseParser.java:4285)
```

If I change query to

```
select c from Customer c where upper(c.name) like %:search% or upper(c.number) like upper(%:search%)
```

or

```
select c from Customer c where upper(c.name) like upper(%:search%) or upper(c.number) like %:search%
```

Then the query validation is okay but it behaves incorrect, the part with upper(%:search%) isn't working.

I've found the following solution for jpql, but this isn't the case for spring data.

```
namedQuery.setParameter("code", "%" + this.value + "%");
```

Anyway I have a workaround:

```
Page<Customer> findByNameContainingIgnoreCaseOrNumberContainingIgnoreCase(String name, String number, Pageable pageable);
```

But is there another solution rather than method with 11 words? 
Thanks!

Comment: as long as c.name and c.number are valid fields then that looks like a bug in your JPA provider (assuming that Spring is not changing the query in the meantime of course ...)